# How do I add header and footer to all pages using a template?

Tags: mediawiki

I am transcribing this book on Sanskrit Wikisource.

[https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/अनुक्रमणिका:Samasakusumavali.djvu](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE:Samasakusumavali.djvu)

I need the page numbers to appear automatically in footer section.
And the header section should have the name of the book.

```
समासकुसुमावलि:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Do I have to add it on all pages manually?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for SO, being either too broad or just not about programming in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page number is what goes after the last page in the URL or page title in wiki (e.g., `१०` in `https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D:Samasakusumavali.djvu/%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A6`), you can insert something like this at the end bottom of each wiki page:

```
----
{{SUBPAGENAME}}
```

But the above in a general *MediaWiki* advice. *WikiSource* has a special [policy](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Help:Page_numbers) (also, [this](https://wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource:ProofreadPage#The_%3Cpagelist/%3E_tag)) on page numbers. Page numbers are configured with `<pagelist>` tag on the main wikipage for the source, and it seems that it has already been done in your case: `<pagelist 1TO9=highroman  10=1/>`. I don't think there is a way to make these page numbers Indic.

And I suspect that *WikiSource* does not want you to add headers and footers with the book name or page numbers manually — but look at the [Header template](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D:Header).

Comment: That will print 10 and not 1 as shown on the original page.